# How can I start the browser AFTER the server started listening?

Tags: http, go, server

In Go, how can I start the browser AFTER the server started listening?

Preferably the simplest way possible.

My code so far, super dumbed down to the point:

```
package main

import (  
    // Standard library packages
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/skratchdot/open-golang/open"
    // Third party packages
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)


// go get github.com/toqueteos/webbrowser

func main() {  
    // Instantiate a new router
    r := httprouter.New()

    // Add a handler on /test
    r.GET("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
        // Simply write some test data for now
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome!\n")
    })
    
    //open.Run("https://google.com/")
     
    // open.Start("https://google.com")

    // http://127.0.0.1:3000/test
    // Fire up the server
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:3000", r)
    fmt.Println("ListenAndServe is blocking")  
    open.RunWith("http://localhost:3000/test", "firefox")  
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Comment: In Go it is not very complicated to make the "blocking" `http.ListenAndServe` "nonblocking": `go http.ListenAndServe(...)`, maybe with some error handling.  So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Volker: The problem is, this are my first steps in go, so I'm not very fluent in it, yet, otherwise I'd just create a new thread and sleep for a few milliseconds before opening the browser; and at the moment I have other things to do ;) Also, if ListenAndServer was non-blocking, it would exit the moment the main program exits (AFAIK), which would be immediately.

Comment: Just run `http.ListenAndServe()` in a separate go routine, then sleep a while (e.g 200ms), then open in browser.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Open the listener, start the browser and then enter the server loop:

```
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:3000")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// The browser can connect now because the listening socket is open.

err := open.Start("http://localhost:3000/test")
if err != nil {
     log.Println(err)
}

// Start the blocking server loop.

log.Fatal(http.Serve(l, r))
```

There's no need to poll as shown in another answer. The browser will connect if the listening socket is open before the browser is started.

ListenAndServe is a convenience function that opens a socket and calls Serve. The code in this answer splits out these steps so the browser can be opened after listening starts but before the blocking call to Serve.

Comment: Interesting, I like it ! Threading is not even required. Very nice.

Comment: This is the correct answer really. Listening socket has an internal fixed-size backlog queue which can accept connections even if there is no `Accept` being actively waiting at given time. That's why it works.

Comment: [`server.ListenAndServe`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L2576) also seems to use a `tcpKeepAliveListener`. It seems to set the TCP keepalive of sockets to 3 minutes. You should probably do this too.

Answer (score 14):

If there is no error, [`http.ListenAndServe()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) will never return. So you shouldn't add code after that except code that handles failure.

You have to start a new goroutine, so `ListenAndServe()` is called in one goroutine, and code checking if it is up should run on the other goroutine.

And you can check if your server is up by making a simple HTTP `GET` call to it, for example using [`http.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get).

The following example delays startup for 7 seconds on purpose. The new goroutine starts an endless `for` loop that checks if server is up, sleeping 1 second between attempts.

Example:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hi!"))
})

go func() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)

        log.Println("Checking if started...")
        resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8081")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Failed:", err)
            continue
        }
        resp.Body.Close()
        if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
            log.Println("Not OK:", resp.StatusCode)
            continue
        }

        // Reached this point: server is up and running!
        break
    }
    log.Println("SERVER UP AND RUNNING!")
}()

log.Println("Starting server...")
time.Sleep(time.Second * 7)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
```

Example output:

```
2015/09/23 13:53:03 Starting server...
2015/09/23 13:53:04 Checking if started...
2015/09/23 13:53:06 Failed: Get http://localhost:8081: dial tcp [::1]:8081: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2015/09/23 13:53:07 Checking if started...
2015/09/23 13:53:09 Failed: Get http://localhost:8081: dial tcp [::1]:8081: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2015/09/23 13:53:10 Checking if started...
2015/09/23 13:53:10 SERVER UP AND RUNNING!
```

Answer (score 0):

The API is not absolutely terrible, but let's just say "It takes some getting used to". Here is how you use custom attributes on the Server struct:

```
s := &http.Server{
    Addr:           cnf.API_SERVER_ADDRESS,
    Handler:        h,
    ReadTimeout:    0, // 1 * time.Minute,
    WriteTimeout:   30 * time.Minute,
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
}

go func() {

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", cnf.API_SERVER_ADDRESS)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(`{"server_state":"listening"}`)
    log.Fatal(s.Serve(l));
}()
```

because if you instead use:

```
http.Serve(l, handler)
```

then you can't define custom properties on the server

Comment: How can I shutdown the server?