# Log when server is started

Tags: http, go

Is there any way to print something when the http server starts? For instance `"Server is started at port 8080"`

In Node (using Express), it would be like:

```
app.listen(8080, function() { console.log('Server started at port 8080') });
```

This is my code:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", MyHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Go: How can I start the browser AFTER the server started listening?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738188/go-how-can-i-start-the-browser-after-the-server-started-listening)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use Go's [log](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) package:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    addr := ":8080"
    http.HandleFunc("/", MyHandler)
    log.Println("listen on", addr)
    log.Fatal( http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil) )
}
```

[`http.ListenAndServe`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) opens the server port, and blocks forever waiting for clients.  If it fails to open the port, the `log.Fatal` call will report the problem and exit the program.

Answer (score 9):

You can't print a log message after `ListenAndServe` since it blocks and never returns, so basically you have two main options:

1. Print "Starting server on port...." and that's it - BUT if `ListenAndServe` could not start it returns an error, so unless there's some error or panic printed because of that, you can assume the server started.
2. Call `ListenAndServe` in a separate goroutine, and make sure there was no error returned and print "Server started..." etc.

I personally prefer the first approach.

Answer (score 9):

To run `ListenAndServe` in a goroutine as mentioned by Not_a_Golfer, you can use an unbuffered, blocking channel to run it in a goroutine and also keep the server alive.

The following example creates a channel called `done` where `<-done` will keep the server alive as it waits for the goroutine to finish, which it won't in this case. Typically, the goroutine will tell the main function it is finished by executing `done <- true`.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello World"))
}

func main() {
    port := "8080"

    http.HandleFunc("/", MyHandler)

    done := make(chan bool)
    go http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil)
    log.Printf("Server started at port %v", port)
    <-done
}
```

Here's a larger example that has the server verify it is operational, using `Listen` and `Serve` separately. The nice thing about doing it this way is you can capture an incorrect port easily.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello World"))
}

func main() {
    port := "8080"

    http.HandleFunc("/", MyHandler)

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    done := make(chan bool)
    go http.Serve(listener, nil)

    // Log server started
    log.Printf("Server started at port %v", port)

    // Attempt to connect
    log.Printf("Fetching...")
    res, err := http.Get("http://" + listener.Addr().String())
    log.Printf("Received: %v, %v", res, err)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    res.Write(os.Stdout)

    <-done
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or to run log command in a goroutine:

```
    errStart := false
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        if !errStart {
            log.Info("Server is started at port 8080")
        }
    }()
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        errStart = true
        log.Error(...)
    }
```

Comment: Using sleep is not good here. This makes things unnecessarily complex and non-idiomatic.