# get notified when http.Server starts listening

Tags: go

When I look at the net/http server interface, I don't see an obvious way to get notified and react when the http.Server comes up and **starts** listening:

```
ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

The function doesn't return until the server actually shuts down. I also looked at the Server type, but there doesn't appear to be anything that lets me tap into that timing. Some function or a channel would have been great but I don't see any.

Is there any way that will let me detect that event, or am I left to just sleeping "enough" to fake it?

Comment: Do you mean with something like a `log`?

Comment: Do you want to know when the listener has been created? what problem are you trying to solve? You can pass a listener directly to the server if you want with [`Server.Serve`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Serve).

Comment: I'd like to be able to take certain action such as "this http server is open for business". For example, one can imagine a scenario where you want to register this server to a registry so it becomes part of some service discovery once the server is up and actually accepting connections. Then clients could discover this instance and start sending traffic.

I doubt the listener creation is an answer, because it merely creates the listener instance but it isn't actually accepting connections at that point, right?

Comment: @sjlee: well, once the listener is created the OS will accept connections into the syn queue, so they're not going to be rejected. Service discovery usually relies on other systems like health/port checks, so registering a service as it comes up isn't an issue.

Comment: OK that's a fair point. Thanks for that. In general, I'm still intrigued that there isn't a channel or a func that can be provided to be notified when the server comes up. It strikes me as a pretty useful functionality.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ListenAndServe is a helper function that opens a listening socket and then serves connections on that socket. Write the code directly in your application to signal when the socket is open:

```
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Signal that server is open for business. 

if err := http.Serve(l, rootHandler); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

If the signalling step does not block, then http.Serve will easily consume any backlog on the listening socket.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32742904/5728991

Comment: I'll accept the answer. Thanks! One note is that the listener route is more involved, especially for ListenAndServeTLS(). It appears you kind of end up replicating some http/Server code to have the same behavior. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14374 and https://github.com/golang/go/commit/b5f0aff49503e31002b33198e06708e263c445a7.