# How to notify when HTTP server starts successfully

Tags: go

I'm trying to start an HTTP server in Go, and when the server is started, a message should be printed, in case of an error, an error message should be printed.

Given the following code:

```
const (
    HTTPServerPort = ":4000"
)

func main() {
    var httpServerError = make(chan error)
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

    setupHTTPHandlers()

    waitGroup.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer waitGroup.Done()

        httpServerError <- http.ListenAndServe(HTTPServerPort, nil)
    }()

    if <-httpServerError != nil {
        fmt.Println("The Logging API service could not be started.", <-httpServerError)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Logging API Service running @ http://localhost" + HTTPServerPort)
    }

    waitGroup.Wait()
}
```

When I do start the application, I don't see anything printed to the console, where I would like to see:

`Logging API Service running @ http://localhost:4000`

When I change the port to an invalid one, the following output is printed to the console:

`fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

`goroutine 1 [chan receive]:`
`main.main()`
`...app.go:45 +0x107`
`exit status 2`

Could anyone point me in the right direction so that I know what I'm doing wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get notified when http.Server starts listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597248/get-notified-when-http-server-starts-listening)

Comment: Do you really need that? HTTP server start should be really fast. I would rather check to see what in your code makes it slow. Do you have any IO in handlers initializers?

Answer (score 11):

You can't do this unless you change the logic in your code or use `Listen` and `Serve` separately. Because `ListenAndServe` is a blocking function. If there something unexpected happens, it will return you an error. Provided it is not, it will keep blocking running the server. There is neither an event that is triggered whenever a server is started.

Let's run `Listen` and `Serve` separately then.

```
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Signal that server is open for business. 

if err := http.Serve(l, rootHandler); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598343/4792552.

P.S. `net.Listen` doesn't block because it runs in background. In other means, it simply spawns a socket connection in OS level and returns you with the details/ID of it. Thus, you use that ID to proxy orders to that socket.

Comment: That makes sense. I tought that even `serveAndListen` is a blocking function, I would be able to solve this using a channel but it seems that it isn't :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your if statement will always read from the `httpServerError` channel. However the only time something writes to that is if the server fails.

Try a `select` statement:

```
select{
case err := <-httpServerError
    fmt.Println("The Logging API service could not be started.", err)
default:
    fmt.Println("Logging API Service running @ http://localhost" + HTTPServerPort
}
```

The `default` case will be ran if the channel does not have anything on it.

Notice this does not read from the channel twice like your example. Once you read a value from a channel, its gone. Think of it as a queue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And does the 'main' thread blocks until a channel is empty or how does that function in golang?

Comment: So everything will exit once the `main` function does. So your `WaitGroup` will block for you. An alternative would be to put the `select`-statement in a go routine and let the `ListenAndServe` block the exit of the `main` function.

Comment: This still will get to a 'Deadlock'.

Comment: Don't do this. There is no guarantee that the goroutine which calls ListenAndServe has run before your select reads from the channel. Even if ListenAndServe will fail immediately (eg try listening on an invalid port number), it hasn't run yet so there is nothing on the channel when it is read so you'll get the success message.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old post, but reflection helped me out.
We are waiting for the internal listeners to be populated and by doing that we know when the actual listeners were started even before the code is doing "accept" on the socket.

```
func waitForHttpStartByReflection(httpServer *http.Server) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(httpServer).Elem()
    listenersVal := val.FieldByName("listeners")
    listenersVal = reflect.NewAt(listenersVal.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(listenersVal.UnsafeAddr())).Elem()

    for {
        listenersValue := listenersVal.Interface().(map[*net.Listener]struct{})
        if len(listenersValue) > 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```