# go does not write file from container unless application is manually started from container

Tags: docker, go, logging

I've written a little golang application. It do two things:

- handle http://localhost:5000
- write a log each seconds

This application is inside a docker container. The logger you can see is mine, is just an exercise. Application start. If I curl http://localhost:5000 I can see "Ciao, mondo!". But the logger does not starts. The strange thing is that if I go into the container, and I run the application by hand. The logger start to log. I thought this can be a problem of permissions.

### Here the docker-compose.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
    app:
        container_name: 'go_docker_app'
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: .
        volumes:
            - ./logs:/app/logs
            - .:/opt/app/api
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
```

### Here the main.go file

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "time"
        "github.com/sensorario/gol"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer);
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil);

    go forever()
    select{}
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Ciao, mondo!");
}

func forever() {
    l := gol.NewCustomLogger("/app");
    for {
        l.Info(fmt.Sprintf("%v+\n", time.Now()));
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

### Here the Dockerfile

I've tried more solutions. For example creating logger.log from Dockerfile. I dont think is a problem of permissions because I have no errors.

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...
RUN go build -o /application
EXPOSE 5000
RUN touch /app/logs/logger.log
CMD ["/application"]
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer to your question, but: why `go forever()` followed by `select {}` when you could just `forever()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by running `ListenAndServe` before your goroutine. `go forever()` never execute, so it will not output any log file.

> The strange thing is that if I go into the container, and I run the application by hand. The logger start to log.

I assume that You exec on running container, where one instance of your app is alredy running so the **Port 5000** is alredy taken. You don't have any error handling, so it skips it and go to the `forever()` function. Empty `select{}` won't be needed, coz `ListenAndServe` will "block" the program: a nice explenation https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598343/14484111

```golang
func main() {

    go forever()
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer);

    // added error validating
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil);
    log.Fatal(err)

    // or shorter version
    // log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil))

}
```