# Is there any way to calculate the startup time of Go app?

Tags: performance, go, testing, performance-testing

I tried to calculate the time a Go app takes to start up and accept requests.
I tried to do it using:

```
func main() {
    start:=time.Now()
    repo.CreateConnection()
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    r := bookController.Controller(router)
    fmt.Println("Starting server on the port 8080...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))
    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}
```

But the console only prints till  *Starting server on the port 8080...*

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/admin/go #gosetup
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o /private/var/folders/t3/1fk2w7y55qs1dfxbxbvpsn9h0000gp/T/___go_build_payments_go_performance go-performance #gosetup
/private/var/folders/t3/1fk2w7y55qs1dfxbxbvpsn9h0000gp/T/___go_build_go_performance
Successfully connected!
Starting server on the port 8080...
```

Is there anyway to display the correct startup time?
By startup time, I mean the time this app take to starts listening to port 8080.

Comment: Well, it depends on a) how you define "start up time" and b) how accurate you want to be.  No program can accurately calculate it's own startup time, since the program can't start counting until after at least some startup has occurred.

Comment: If you don't need perfect accuracy, you could have an early-executing statement start a timer (such as the first statement in `main()`, an `init()` function, or a package-level variable declaration).  Then you could consult that timer immediately before executing `http.ListenAndServe`.  But that won't count the startup time prior to starting your timer, and it won't count the time between calling `http.ListenAndServe`, and actually opening a socket to listen.

Comment: What are you using this calculation for? That could help inform a reasonable approach.

Comment: In spring boot we get the startup time at the end of running the project,stating that this application was started in X seconds .I just wanted to know a way to do so in Go.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like accuracy is not important. The approach I described should do it for you.

Comment: In your approach,shouldn't the timer be after *http.ListenAndServe* ?In springboot,it usually calculates time(Startup time) after it starts listening to the port. I have already applied this approach (mentioned in question),but nothing gets printed after the server starts listening to that port.

Comment: After `http.ListenAndServe` the program is exiting, so that would be telling you how long the program ran, not how long it took to start up.

Comment: See [How can I start the browser AFTER the server started listening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738188/how-can-i-start-the-browser-after-the-server-started-listening)

Comment: The time ListenAndServe takes before it starts accepting requests is negligible for your use-case, so measuring to just before this call is good enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest, which should be good enough for most cases, would be something like this:

```golang
package main

var start = time.Now()

/* place any other package variable declarations after `start` */

func main() {
    /* set up code */
    fmt.Printf("Startup took aprox %v\n", time.Since(start))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(...))
}
```

This ensures that `start` is initialized as early as possible in the execution of your program, before other package-level variables, and before any `init` functions.  Then as the very last thing before launching the server, it displays the elapsed time.