# Print message after blocking method in goroutine

Tags: go

I use the [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) web framework to host an API server.
The documentation says the `Run` method will block the calling goroutine indefinitely.

Now, my question is: How do you typically print a log message when the `Run` method **succeeded**? Something like *"API listening on port 3000"*

Right now, my code looks like this. But as expected, the 2nd line will not be printed due to the blocking call on the first line.

```golang
log.Fatal(server.Run(":" + port))
log.InfoFn("API listening on port %s\n", port)
```

Comment: You can’t, at least in any way that makes sense. You either print when it returns, or print it concurrently which isn’t technically after it started. The server may have a way to pass in already listening connection for similar use cases, but it really makes no difference for almost any program to print the message first.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32742904/5728991.  Create a listener, print the message and then call RunListener.

Comment: The easier approach is to log before the call to Run.  Run fails quickly if it cannot start the server. Your call to log.Fatal will print that error.